# Recursion depth and different parsing

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xslt

I'm fairly new to xslt. So what im trying to do, is parse a book in xml to an html. A Basic example would be this.

```
<book>
    <title>
        Some important title
    </title>
    <section>
        <title>animal</title>
        <kw>RealAnimal</kw>
        <kw>something|something more about it</tkw>
        <para>Some really important facts</para>
        <section>
            <title>something</title>
            <kw>something else</kw>
            <para>Enter Text</para>
        </section>
        <section>
            <title>Even more</title>
            <kw>and more</kw>
            <para>hell of a lot more</para>
        </section>
    </section>
</book>
```

a section can have an unknown number of subsections. So obviously i need to handle this with recusrion. so far i designed 2 templates, in order to handle a book and a section, based on my needs.

```
<xsl:template match="book">
<html>
    <body>
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[title]">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="title" /></li>
    <!-- do something more here -->
</xsl:template>
```

what i cant figure out is, can i get my current recursion depth, because i want to make a decision which kind of header to use based on the depth.

Also, the book is supposed to consist of 2 parts. its normal content at the beginning, like header and para below that header. and an index in the end. This leads me to believe that i need to parse it in 2 different ways within one document, but how would i do that? Any hints or Code would be greatly appreciated

so i figured out how to make section and subsection headers with numbers like a list in Word.

```
<xsl:number level="multiple" />
```

gives me for a subsection x.y basend on parents section position and its own position. what i now want is that it gives me the number of groups, as it groups the values based on the depth, but i cant figure out how

what id expect is that it parses to

```
<h1>Some important title</h1>
...
<h2> animal </h2>
...
<h3> something </h3>
...
<h3> Even more </h3>
```

and if i were to add another section to the "something"-section it would be h4 and so on...

### solved it like this

```
<xsl:param name="depth"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="6 > $depth">
        <xsl:element name="h{$depth}">
            <xsl:number level="multiple" />.
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <h6><xsl:number level="multiple" />. <xsl:value-of select="title" /></h6>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Why don't you give us a hint regarding the output you expect? Using an example that has some nested sub-sections would be helpful in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> well what im trying to do is set h2 for section as subsection for
>   book, and h3 for a subsection of section

Here's one way you could do this - with unlimited nesting of subsections:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/book">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="3"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subsection">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:element name="h{$depth}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this **is** recursive **and** unlimited; AFAIK, HTML will run out of levels after `h6`.

---

### Edit:

> a subsection isnt named subsection, it just a section as a child of
>   another section.

Well, then this could be simpler. Or at least shorter.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/book">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="section">
                <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="2"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>  
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:element name="h{$depth}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section">
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit 2:

> im supposed to set h2-h5 for th first 4, and h6 after that.

If you mean you want to limit the heading to a maximum of `h6` regardless of the section's depth, then change this:

```
    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1"/>
```

to:

```
    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + ($depth &lt; 6)"/>
```

Comment: this looks like i could adapt it to my needs, a subsection isnt named subsection, it just a section as a child of another section. im supposed to set h2-h5 for th first 4, and h6 after that.

Comment: @DanielBo "*im supposed to set h2-h5 for th first 4, and h6 after that.*" I am afraid that makes no sense to me. I suggest again you edit your question and provide a [minimal yet complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of both input and required output.

Comment: @DanielBo I am still not sure I understand this, but have a look at edit #2 above.

Comment: thats not exactly my solution, but it gave me an idea on how to solve the problem, going to accept your answer and post my final solution for it :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try tinkering with "count(ancestor::*)" if you really want to know how deep you are.  However, I'd suggest taking a look at automatic numbering first, just in case it does the trick.  It even handles nested items pretty handily.

"XSLT's xsl:number instruction makes it easy to insert a number into your result document. Its value attribute lets you name the number to insert, but if you really want to add a specific number to your result, it's much simpler to add that number as literal text. When you omit the value attribute from an xsl:value-of instruction, the XSLT processor calculates the number based on the context node's position in the source tree or among the nodes being counted through by an xsl:for-each instruction, which makes it great for automatic numbering."

[XML.com reference page](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/11/06/tr.html)

Comment: well what im trying to do is set h2 for section as subsection for book, and h3 for a subsection of section.

Comment: I noticed your comment in the other response, (about using H2-H6).  You could do an <xsl:choose> that checks on the nesting level (ancestor or number, depending on what method you end up using) and let H6 be the default choice. Looks like the ancestor option may be your simplest bet, in this case.

Comment: i posted my solution :)